# Bad Sorting in R

Tags: r

I am trying to sort a dataframe and I can see that R is sorting the data incorrectly.

```
state <- "TX"
data <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
sbd <- subset(data, State == state)
log_vec <- sbd$Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Failure != "Not Available"
sbd2 <- sbd[log_vec,]   
sorted <- sbd[order(as.numeric(sbd2$Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Failure)),]
```

Now when I do

```
head(sorted,5)[17]
```

I can see

```
> head(sorted, 5)[17]
     Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Failure
3935                                                        8.1
4080                                                       12.6
3954                                                        8.7
4097                                                        9.9
3962                                                        8.8
```

Why did that 12.6 appear in the list??

My input CSV is available [here](https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/rprog%2Fdata%2FProgAssignment3-data.zip)

Comment: You should use sbd2 not sbd on the last line.

Comment: @ApprenticeQueue: I agree that using `sbd2` rather than `sbd` in the last line should solve the problem, which seems to be arising because `R` will wrap the index vector if it is shorter than the vector being indexed and thereby select some incorrect rows with the wrapped index vector. I suggest you may wish to elaborate on your comment in the form of an answer.

Comment: @Simon,if you wrote all that, you should answer it then!  Otherwise I will be repeating you.  LOL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Apprentice Queue noted, using `sbd2` rather than `sbd` in the last line should solve the problem, which seems to be arising because R will wrap the index vector if it is shorter than the vector being indexed and thereby select some incorrect rows with the wrapped index vector.